# Vagrant / Vaprobash problems on El Capitan

Tags: vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Since upgrading to El Cap, I've had constant issues with Vagrant / Vaprobash. This is happening on two different macs, and both have been upgraded with the latest Vagrant and VirtualBox builds.

The VM does get started using `vagrant up` (at least, if you look at the box in the VirtualBox admin it's running, even though you can't connect to it), but during the startup it times out constantly:

```
    Bringing machine 'Vaprobash' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> Vaprobash: Checking if box 'ubuntu/trusty64' is up to date...
==> Vaprobash: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> Vaprobash: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> Vaprobash: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    Vaprobash: Adapter 1: nat
    Vaprobash: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> Vaprobash: Forwarding ports...
    Vaprobash: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> Vaprobash: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> Vaprobash: Booting VM...
==> Vaprobash: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    Vaprobash: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    Vaprobash: SSH username: vagrant
    Vaprobash: SSH auth method: private key
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    Vaprobash: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
Timed out while waiting for the machine to boot. This means that
Vagrant was unable to communicate with the guest machine within
the configured ("config.vm.boot_timeout" value) time period.

If you look above, you should be able to see the error(s) that
Vagrant had when attempting to connect to the machine. These errors
are usually good hints as to what may be wrong.

If you're using a custom box, make sure that networking is properly
working and you're able to connect to the machine. It is a common
problem that networking isn't setup properly in these boxes.
Verify that authentication configurations are also setup properly,
as well.
```

When the box finally "runs", I can't connect to it. If I use VirtualBox to open a terminal, it seems like the connection timeout is a prompt where the VM is waiting for input for a login screen. However, this login should be handled by Vagrant.

Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much tearing of hair and grinding of teeth, reinstalling Vagrant, VirtualBox and removing / installing all my box images several times, I finally was able to make this work by totally removing all vagrant data (`rm -rf ~/.vagrant.d/`), uninstalling the vagrant app (`rm -rf /usr/bin/vagrant`) and then installing the vagrant app fresh.

Then I executed `vagrant up` and it regenerated all keys, which finally seemed to do the trick. I had removed and regenerated the keys manually, as well as copying my own `id_rsa` over the `insecure_private_key` file in `.vagrant.d` with no luck-- and reinstalling vagrant without first removing all data will not resolve the problem.

Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

is your vagrant file have `vb.gui = true` ? if not then add like :

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.gui = true
end
```

if this is ok then it may be issue with your ssh key.
you can try following steps:

download private key from [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/vagrant) and try to login in vagrant box.

```
ssh -i privatekey vagrant@ip
```

or

download private key from [here](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/keys/vagrant) and store somewhere and add below line in vagrant file :

```
config.ssh.private_key_path="full_path_of_ssh_privatekey"
```

then try to login using command:

```
vagrant ssh vmname
```

or 
it may be your vagrant public key is not store in vagrant vm. so you can create shell script `test.sh` and add following line in `test.sh` file

```
mkdir /home/vagrant/.ssh
wget --no-check-certificate -O authorized_keys 'https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/raw/master/keys/vagrant.pub'
mv authorized_keys /home/vagrant/.ssh
chown -R vagrant /home/vagrant/.ssh
chmod -R go-rwsx /home/vagrant/.ssh
```

and use shell provisioner in `Vagrantfile` like :

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "test.sh"
```

then provision that vm either

```
vagrant reload vmname --provision
```

or you can recreate vm using command

```
vagrant destroy vmname
vagrant up vmname
```

Comment: @pl_rock-- thanks, but the point is that vagrant should be able to login by itself-- I've never needed a GUI in the past to login.

Comment: i also faced same problem many time but it shows when my ssh key not at correct location.

Comment: any suggestions on fixing the ssh key issue?

Comment: download private key https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/tree/master/keys  and try to ssh using `ssh -i keys vagrant@ip`